# Slicing using frama-c

Tags: c, frama-c, program-slicing

I'm using **frama-c** in order to do some experiments on program slicing. The tool is great and there are a lot of different types of slicing (by result or by statement, for example). I'm using a program data structure like:

```
typedef struct ComplexData {
    int x;
    int y;
    char string_[100];
    size_t n;
} ComplexData;
```

It's just an example in order to understand how *frama-c* can slice the program by the result produced by the function. Basically, the *main* method calls a function which returns a value of the type *ComplexData*. **How the comparison between different executions is performed? There is a check for each value of the struct?** Like [this](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?x_1%20%3D%20x_2%20%5C%20%5Cwedge%20%5C%20y_1%20%3D%20y_2%20%5C%20%5Cwedge%20%5C%20string%20%3D%20string%5E%7B%27%7D%20%5C%20%5Cwedge%20%5C%20n_1%20%3D%20n_2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-slice-return f` of Frama-C instructs the slicer to keep all statements that contribute to the computation of the return code of `f`. For your type `ComplexData`, this means the contents of any of the fields. Any statement that computes e.g. `y`, or one the characters in `string_`, will be kept.

Regarding *comparison between different executions*, static slicers actually work differently. They **approximate** the behavior of each function, across all possible executions. (In the case of Frama-C, this is done using a technique known as [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation).)  Thus, there is no need to *compare* two executions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear reply. Most of the articles that I read, describe _dynamic slicing_ and in particular they tried to compare the trajectory on different executions. So, may abstract interpretation used only for _static slicing_? Finally, regarding what I read, the trajectory was stored in an output file and I have only seen criterion based on data primitives like _integers_. For this reason, I thought that there was also a similar comparison for data structures. Even if, in that case one needs to compare each field.

Comment: Right, I forgot about dynamic slicing. I edited my answer accordingly. Abstract interpretation is inherently static, so I dont think it can be used for dynamic slicing.

Comment: Ok. Yes, you're right. Anyway, it could have great advantages when you have to compare complex data structures.